# React router V3 and webpack 2 code splitting wont work

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, code-splitting

I am trying to code split the application based on routes using webpack. I have added the **System.import** in the  tag. Here is my Routes snippet file:

```
function errorLoading(error) {
  throw new Error(`Dynamic page loading failed: ${error}`);
}

// Loading modules!
function loadRoute(cb) {
  return module => cb(null, module.default);
}

<Route path="/about" getComponent = {(location, cb) => {
  System.import('../containers/legal/components/about/')
    .then(loadRoute(cb))
    .catch(errorLoading);
}}
/>
```

As far as I have seen in the docs, the only thing that we need for code splitting based on the routes is **System.import** in the  tag. I have not changed anything in `Webpack.config.js`. Anyway here is my webpack config:

```
const devConfig = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
  },
  stats: {
    color: true,
    reasons: true,
    chunks: true,
  },
  entry: {
    app: [
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
      path.resolve('./src/index'),
    ],
    vendor: ['react', 'react-dom', 'reduxsauce'],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('public'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.[name].js',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  target: 'web',
  plugins: [
    new ProgressBarPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'process.env': webpackEnvs.development })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/ }
    ],
  },
};
```

At the end, only app and vendor js files are created. No extra js file based on that specific route is created. But even after using the System.import, only the separate file is not created, but works properly.